# font will not show in Mac safari 7

Tags: html, css, macos, fonts, safari

I'm embedding `Franklin Gothic Book Regular` on my website using `font-face`. The font is shown in windows firefox, chrome and safari but isn't visible in mac safari 7(I am testing via saucelabs). here's my font face code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'franklin_gothic_bookregular';
src: url('../fonts/franklin_gothic_book-webfont.eot');
src: local('franklin gothic book regular'), url('../fonts/franklin_gothic_book-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('../fonts/franklin_gothic_book-webfont.woff') format('woff'),  url('../fonts/franklin_gothic_book-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),  url('../fonts/franklin_gothic_book-webfont.svg#franklin_gothic_bookregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

what am I doing wrong? here's the site if you want to take a look: http://goo.gl/mBnb30 . Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like this font is the only one you're calling a local src on... does it work if you remove that bit?

Comment: no. I have tried local because I saw it on a blog that it works for mac, but it isn't working for me!! :'(

Comment: I'm using Mac Safari 7.0.2, it works for me.